# How do I create a dynamic array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a homework assignment that seems to be easiest completed with a dynamic array.  How would I go about doing this in c++?  I tried searching online for dynamic c++ arrays but nothing has been helpful.  I am trained in c# and can't believe something this simple wouldn't exist in c++.  If not how can I complete this?

You've been hired by Sochi Sports Speed Skating (S4) to write software to calculate the average time of a random number of skaters in the Short Track Speed Skating event.  Write a Visual C++ program to prompt for and read the times of skaters, one at a time.  When the user enters -1, that signals the end of the list (it’s the sentinel).  Assume the user will only enter positive real numbers.  After the user enters -1, check whether they entered any other numbers.  If they only entered -1 (the sentinel), you cannot calculate an average since the number of skaters is zero and you would be dividing by zero.  After the user enters -1, output the following, one per line, with the label in one column and the value in another column.  Format the average time to three decimal places.

Comment: `dynamic c++ array` pretty much any of the hits...

Comment: Use a list instead? How did you do it in C#? I imagine you used a list or a ArrayList

Comment: "I tried searching online for dynamic c++ arrays but nothing has been helpful."  Indicating I already tried that......

Comment: @aidenkael Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`Dynamic memory manangement`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) features to make your life easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `std::vector`.  That is basically the same as an array but its size can be adjusted how ever you want.